# Disqus and retrieving logged in user

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, disqus

I creating a system, which could be considered a wiki, and I am going to use either Disqus or Intense debate to display comments on the articles on the site.

Is it possible using Disqus or Intense debate to ask their api to retrieve the username/userid of the user viewing the page, so I can log which users are editing my articles?

I could manually ask the Facebook API, Open Id, Twitter etc. for the userId, but it would be a lot simpler if there was just one API to request the Id of the user..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who are interested, I chose [janrain](http://www.janrain.com/) to use as log in, and then I am creating the comments feature myself.