# Javascript configuration for django-disqus not working

Tags: python, django, disqus

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so I'm sorry if my question is too naive. I'm building a Django based website on Heroku, and I've added the Disqus comment system using django-disqus. Users can also login on my site, so naturally I don't want them to enter login details again when the post comments with Disqus - I want the user to get registered with Disqus automatically (at least the Name+Email form should fill after inferring details of the user from request.user).

I found some stuff online to do this (they all suggested the same thing): [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177397/import-logged-in-user-disqus-comments). They say that I must put the following in the program's Javascript code, before the Disqus iframe renders:

```
var disqus_def_name = "{{ user.get_full_name}}";
var disqus_def_email = "{{ user.email }}";
```

If you check [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables), the Javascript configuration is specified in the same  block as embed.js. Since I'm using Django, that code is subsumed by my templatetags, so I must add the above (name and email) configurations to some other JS  block. I added it to the first main block, but it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those javascript variables are now deprecated - users who want to register on Disqus must sign up for Disqus themselves. The good news is that they only need to do this once, and a lot of people might already have accounts.

Comment: Thanks! Although this is bad for me, because I don't want users that are already signed into my website to enter their details again for comments.

Comment: Ah, what you're actually looking for is actually single sign-on. See here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/684744 - you'll need to contact us to get it enabled, put ATTN Ryan when contacting us here: http://disqus.com/support/